# Missing fuses - is it OK?

Tags: electrical, wiring, fuse, fuse-panel

I recently got the car horn replaced and the mechanic changed the 2xfuses for the horn from 7.5 amps to 15 amps each after installing the new horn. This is because when testing the horn, it blew a fuse and it was realised that the new horn requires 30amp fuse (whereas the old one required 15 amps).

I had a look at the fuse box, which had several empty slots (see photo):
[image]

Here's a picture of the under side of the fuse-panel cover, that does not state some fuses are optional or any such thing:
[image]

Should I purchase an assorted pack of fuses and replace the empty slots with the appropriate ones, or is it OK to leave this as is?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fuse box is designed for all vehicles and positions only used as needed for each vehicle.

First check if those empty fuse slots have terminals in them, without terminals adding fuses does nothing.

Then check the legend to see if that item or function is fitted or valid for the vehicle.

Example : A fuse position can be provided for diesel heater plugs which are not relevant on a petrol vehicle.